# Multidimensional loop on two CSV file php

Tags: php, loops, csv

I need to compare two CSV file that both contain two columns: ID and URL and check if the URL are differents. The two file normally, are the same but sometimes it can change. So i have to compare if the ID is the same and if the URL has change. I would like do this with a multidimensional loop (both of files are very big). But i don't understand why at the first match, the loop is stopped.

I try to do this with a while loop:

```
    while ($file_odierno_fr = fgetcsv($product_dinamica_fr, 0, ";", '"')) {
    while ($file_precedente_fr = fgetcsv($product_dinamica_fr_pre, 0, ";", '"' )) {
 // the index [1] is the URL and ID is the index [0]
        if ($file_odierno_fr[1] !== $file_precedente_fr[1]  && $file_odierno_fr[0] == $file_precedente_fr[0]){
            $textMail .= "\n\nURL file odierno: <b>".$file_odierno_fr[1]. "</b>\nURL file pecedente: <b>". $file_precedente_fr[1] . "</b>\n\n";
            fputcsv($file,array($file_odierno_fr[1], $file_precedente_fr[1]),";");
            $sendMail = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
fclose($product_dinamica_fr);
fclose($product_dinamica_fr_pre);
```

But when igo to debug this, i get juste the first match and the rest is ignored. I change some  URL in the file for be sure that all is working.

I think that i can't do while loop like this, but i'm not sure. There is a way for do that with while loop?

Comment: How big are the files? If the files are too big, then it makes sense read the first file completely and then read from the other one only one line at a time to compare.

Comment: Yes they are too big. How can i do that?

Comment: How big? Can you give the size in MB?

Comment: 6 MB but the problem is that i have this for other 6-7 files .... so i have to do the faster algho

Answer (score 0):

Please try to following code and give a feedback:

```php
$separator = ";";
$enclosure = '"';
$lineSize = 0;// 0 := unlimited

$textMail = "";
while($lineNow = fgetcsv($product_dinamica_fr, $lineSize, $separator, $enclosure))
{
    while($linePre = fgetcsv($product_dinamica_fr_pre, $lineSize, $separator, $enclosure))
    {
        $idNow = trim($lineNow[0]);
        $idPre = trim($linePre[0]);
        $urlNow = trim($lineNow[1]);
        $urlPre = trim($linePre[1]);

        // Compare IDs first. If they are not the same, then skip this line
        if($idNow != $idPre)
            continue;

        // If URLs are the same then skip this line
        if( $urlNow == $urlPre)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Set email flag and add info to e-mail content
        $sendMail = TRUE;
        $textMail .= "\n\nURL file odierno: <b>$urlNow</b>\nURL file pecedente: <b>$urlPre</b>\n\n";

        // Write the difference to local file
        fputcsv($file, [$urlNow, $urlPre], ";");
    }
    rewind($product_dinamica_fr_pre);
}
fclose($product_dinamica_fr);
fclose($product_dinamica_fr_pre);

echo $textMail;
```

Comment: not work :/ it stop a the first different URL..

Comment: @s.elettro There was a function call `rewind($filepointer)` missing after the inner while-loop. I updated my code. Please check again.

Comment: @s.elettro Did it work?

Comment: I triy but it take too many time. At the end, the solution that i take, is to put every CSV in two array and loop inside each other...that take less time. thank you anyway

Comment: @s.elettro It takes too long because there are "echo" lines in my solution. I added them in order to see if it works for a couple of lines. Your files have thousands of lines. You should remove the lines with "echo" first then try again. This should work faster than the solution with 2 huge arrays. Please test it and give a feedback.

Comment: @s.elettro Did you try it? Please give a feedback and if it is the case mark the solution as accepted. If you don't do it, it demotivates experienced developers to help other. Because we consume not a short time for your problems.

Comment: Hi, yes i tried but it take still too much time...

Comment: @s.elettro Ok. Both methods have their own disadvantages. Reading the files into PHP arrays needs much more memory. Reading the content line by line from the files needs more time, because each time a file system access occurs, which is much slower than a memory access. In your case you need at least 15 MB extra storage to save the both files in the memory. It is naturally faster to read all the file content sequentially into arrays in the memory and access there than reading each line from the harddisk.